# Simple spark streaming not printing lines

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to write a spark script that monitors a directory & processes data as it streams in.

In the below, i dont get any errors, but it also doesn't print the files,

Does anyone have any ideas?

```
import findspark
findspark.init()

import pyspark
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.streaming import StreamingContext

conf = (SparkConf()
     .setMaster("local")
     .setAppName("My app")
     .set("spark.executor.memory", "1g"))

sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate(conf=conf)
ssc = StreamingContext(sc, 1) #microbatched every 1 second

lines = ssc.textFileStream('file:///C:/Users/kiera/OneDrive/Documents/logs')#directory of log files, Does not work for subdirectories
lines.pprint()


ssc.start()
ssc.awaitTermination()
```

Comment: Try adding files after starting and pls report back

Comment: I did try that too and unfortunately it didnt ork

Comment: Interesting. I will try with scala